# la dirección de mi web se añade automaticamente a un href

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

No sé que está pasando, pero tengo una etiqueta (a) con un href que llama una (id) para abrir un formulario:

```
  <a href="#Open">abrir formulario</a>
```

lo que sucede es que si hago ediciones en la plantilla de mi web la dirección web se añade a todas las etiquetas que tenga ese tipo de href, quedando así:

```
  <a href="www.miweb.com#Open">abrir formulario</a>
```

y las personas al dar click no se abre el formulario si no que van a la página principal. como lo soluciono?

Comment: revisa los selectores que no estén generalizados

Answer (score 0):

¿qué framework estás usando? hablas de modificación de plantilla ... aún así, está raro eso de que los *anchors* que siguen ese formato se actualicen automáticamente a como expones, no obstante, toma en consideración que en la página donde esté tu formulario, debe haber un *tag* del tipo `<section id="Open">...</section>` que será adonde tu página apuntará cuando hagan click al anchor con el `href="#Open"`.